# Help on printing a 8x8 grid in C

Tags: c, grid

I need help printing a 8x8 grid in C.

A typical 1x1 grid is supposed to look like this:

```
+----+
|    |
|    | 
|    |
+----+
```

But I'm not getting that even though I checked everything that would be causing the problem.

Could you guys look over the code and tell me what the problem is?

```
        int main() {

    row_count = 2;
    col_count = 2;

    strcpy(row0NoX, "-----+");
    strcpy(row1NoX, "     |");
    strcpy(row2NoX, "     |");
    strcpy(row3NoX, "     |");
    strcpy(row4NoX, "-----+");

    printf("Welcome to the Checkerboard program!\n");

    for (row = 0; row < row_count; row++) {

        for (tiny_row = 1; tiny_row < N_ROWS; tiny_row++) {

            printf("%c", row0NoX[strlen(row0NoX)-1]);
            printf("%c", row1NoX[strlen(row1NoX)-1]);
            printf("%c", row2NoX[strlen(row2NoX)-1]);
            printf("%c", row3NoX[strlen(row3NoX)-1]);
            printf("%c", row4NoX[strlen(row4NoX)-1]);


            for (col = 0; col < col_count; col++) {

                switch (checkerboard[row][col]) {
                    case 0:
                        switch (tiny_row) {
                            case 1:
                                printf("%s", row0NoX);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                printf("%s", row1NoX);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                printf("%s", row2NoX);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                printf("%s", row3NoX);
                                break;
                            case 5:                             
                                printf("%s", row4NoX);
                                break;
                            default:
                                printf("Error");
                                break;
                        }                       
                        break;  
                }               
            }
            printf("\n");           
        }       
    }   
    //printf("Enter a command: ");  
    return (0);
}
```

The output is close but somehow I'm missing the |s and the +----+ at the end.

Output for 2x2:

```
+|||+-----+-----+
+|||+     |     |
+|||+     |     |
+|||+     |     |
+|||+-----+-----+
+|||+-----+-----+
+|||+     |     |
+|||+     |     |
+|||+     |     |
+|||+-----+-----+
```

Comment: You need to change your perspective. If it's not working then it's because you obviously _haven't_ checked everywhere. Also, what is the output you're getting?

Comment: @quasiverse: Yeah I know. I think it's the switch case thats causing it. I don't know what could be causing the problem though. I'm very new to C so I haven't got the debugging in C mindset yet. And the output isn't putting out the grid.

Comment: You should put your output in your question by clicking "edit" above and adding it there.

Comment: Yeah, what does it print for 2x2, for example?

Comment: @Watabou Are you sure? It works perfectly for me. Are you sure you're using exactly the same code you posted with the printf("\n") in the right spot?

Comment: @Watabou Nononono! I meant put the "\n" at the end of _everything_ in the for loop.

Comment: @quasiverse: Hmm, yeah I added that after the tiny row loop. You can see it in my edit. Did I place it in the wrong place or something?

Comment: @Watabou At the _end_ of the tiny row loop. At the _very_ _end_! Like, _after_ the col loop!

Comment: @quasiverse: Okay I added it after the break statement and the end of the column loop and I edited my post to reflect the output that I'm getting. It's still not working for me :(

Comment: @Watabou _after_ the col loop but _within_ the tiny row loop. I'll edit my answer to show.

Comment: @quasiverse: It's almost working. Now I have to figure out why it's printing +s instead of | and not printing +----+ at the end.

Comment: @Watabou: It's because you're outputting row0NoX[strlen...] for every row when you should change it to row1, row2 etc.

Comment: @quasiverse: Oh. Right. So I should add those for row1 to 4 right? And that's right after that statement?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to print newlines between rows:

```
        for (tiny_row = 1; tiny_row < N_ROWS; tiny_row++) {

            printf("%c", row0NoX[strlen(row0NoX)-1]);

            for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {

                switch (checkerboard[row][col]) {
                    case 0:
                        switch (tiny_row) {
                            case 1:
                                printf("%s", row0NoX);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                            printf("%s", row1NoX);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            printf("%s", row2NoX);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            printf("%s", row3NoX);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            printf("%s", row4NoX);
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Error");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // printf("\n"); <-- Not here
            }
            printf("\n") // <-- Here
        }
```

Also, you forgot to print the line of -'s at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add that in. Thanks. Oh and I thought I did add the -s. thats row4 right?

Comment: Hmm, okay. I tried that and it still isn't working... I'll edit my question and the output I'm getting now.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE_X 5
#define BLOCK_SIZE_Y 4

void draw_box(int w, int h) {
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y <= h * BLOCK_SIZE_Y; y++) {
        int on_horizontal = !(y % BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
        for(x = 0; x <= w * BLOCK_SIZE_X; x++) {
            int on_vertical = !(x % BLOCK_SIZE_X);
            if (on_horizontal && on_vertical) {
                printf("+");
            } else if (on_horizontal) {
                printf("-");
            } else if (on_vertical) {
                printf("|");
            } else printf(" ");
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, no no. I'd like to use my implementation. And I have assigned strings to character arrays called rowNoX for a reason. It's so that when a user enters 2,3, an X will print at row=2 col = 3. I haven't implemented that yet but planning too after I sort the grid problem out. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your new problem is in this line:

> ```
> for (tiny_row = 1; tiny_row < N_ROWS; tiny_row++) {
> ```

I'm guessing `N_ROWS` is initialized to `5`.

`row4NoX` is the line initialized to all `----`, but since it is never printed, I'm guessing that `tiny_row` is never equal to `5`, and that `for` loop sure looks funny.

(I'll never get used to 1-initialized loops in C, but when I see one used with a `<` test, I assume it is a bug. It might not be the most accurate heuristic in the world, but it's worked well for me so far. :)

The small bit of preachy advice: don't mix variable names and indexes with different numbering schemes. Stick with either 0-indexed or 1-indexed (if you're moving from FORTRAN code :) names, when you try to mix them you often wind up making more mental hurdles than already exist in trying to write reliable software.

Comment: Ah, it might be that because I did set NRows to be equal to 5. Maybe I need to change the tiny row loop to be <= 5.